# Find commande doesn't list existing file

Tags: command-line

Ok so! I search the file `latexindent`. The command `typpe latexindent` given me `latexindent is /Library/TeX/texbin/latexindent`.

I execute `find /Library/TeX/texbin/ -name "*latexindent*"` but I don't have any result. So ok! I goinge to `/Library/TeX/texbin/` and execute `ls *latexindent*` for checking if file exists with this name. My `ls` is an alias of `ls -G` and ok, the file exist, and I see it.

Except that ! If I run `find / -name "*latexindent*"` or `find /Library/TeX/texbin/ -name "*latexindent*"` I don't have any result ! But, if I am inside `/Library/TeX/texbin/` and run `find . -name "*latexindent*"` I see `./latexindent`

I have this[image].

Comment: Please post text (in code format) rather than images. Also, without more info it's impossible to tell what is going on. What is the file's actual name? Does `find /Library/TeX/texbin -name "*latexind*"` find it? How about `ls /Library/TeX/texbin/latexindent`? Also, it looks like you've redefined `ls` -- do any of the answers change if you use `/bin/ls` instead?

Comment: Thank's for your comment. I update my post.

Comment: Can you please run all the commands in Terminal, copy/paste the whole Terminal session (the commands *and* their output) into your question and apply code formatting (the `{}` icon on top of the edit screen) to the whole block? The issue may well be some small typo or such, we only see this if you copy whatever your Terminal shows 1:1.

Comment: Also, `/Library/TeX/texbin` probably is a symlink, pointing to a whole forest of further symlinks :-)

Comment: @nohillside Yes ! That it's :)